# Get Elements with CSS filter

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to find all elements that have a `filter` style applied to them from a CSS file.

For instance

```
.fourty {

    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
.fifty {

    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}
.sixty {

    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

How would I capture those elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about add `class` to the elements which has `filter` ?
Then you can do the following:

```
var $elements = $('.yourClass');
```

Or you can do the following if you don't want to add a class.

```
var $elements = $('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('filter') != 'auto';
});
```

I suggest you to add `opacity` to the css, because `filter` isn't crossbrowser. So your code should be the following.

```
var $elements = $('*').filter(function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    return $element.css('filter') != 'auto' || $element.css('opacity') != 1;
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N75B8/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var foundels = [];

$(els).each(function(){
    if($(this).css('filter') == 'alpha(opacity=60)')
        foundels.push(this);
});
```